# Composer-playground not working in firefox

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

The composer playground web app doesn't work correctly in Firefox. It gives

> Error: Object with ID 'undefined' in collection with ID 'chaincodes'
>   does not exist

in Firefox, but it works perfectly in chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: Clear the cookie and refresh. It was giving me the problem when I deleted network and restarted everything without clearing the cookies.

Comment: Delete the cookies and try again or you can open it in incognito window. It works for me !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got the same problem locally, so the solution as suggested is to **delete your cookies** and browser storage. If you use this locally delete the cookies for localhost

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much, it worked really a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem which I solved by using the following commands

1. First stop the Fabrics and then composer by going to its development folder

   ```
   $cd fabric-dev-servers
   ```

   and then

   ```
   $ ./stopFabric.sh

   $ pkill composer-playground
   ```
2. Remove the .composer folder

   ```
   $ rm -rf ~/.composer
   ```
3. run the following command

   fabric-dev-servers/teardownFabric.sh

Afterwards re-run the `./startFabrics.sh` and `composer-playground` commands, everything will work fine.