# Hyperleger Composer Playground Error

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to start with Hyperledger Composer Playground, but when I access into this link:
https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/editor

I found this error:
Error: Object with ID 'undefined' in collection with ID 'chaincodes' does not exist

I tried to use another browser and I cleaned the cache, but the error occur in any case, also locally. Sometimes the error doesn't appear but when I click on getting started, the load is infinite.

How can I fix it?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you're running into the same issue seen here (assuming you're using the same browser for 'both' attempts above) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708598/composer-playground-not-working-in-firefox - answer is to delete all your cookies as well as local storage clear.

Answer (score 0):

can you try below steps may help

1. Clear browser local storage by running localStorage.clear() on browser console
2. Clear the browser history and cookies
3. restart your browser